# Is there a more user-friendly "general" video game console emulator than RetroArch for x86 Windows?

Tags: windows, emulator

I have collected the ROMs of all the games I grew up with and put them into a digital list which I can sort in various means useful to me, such as "by my personal rating". I'm able to click any of them to launch a command. I'm planning on making them run something like:

```
someemulator.exe "path to the ROM"
```

I believe that this is possible with RetroArch, but I don't like that program. I find the user interface utterly confusing, even after spending many hours with it, and the need to download "cores" (emulator engines) and manually pick the right one for the game just makes me very frustrated.

I don't understand why they designed it this way. Why doesn't the program pick the best "core" and skip the bad, broken ones which just crash when you load a ROM, or run them so badly they are not meaningful to ever use?

Also, I find the whole way it's designed to be extremely counter-intuitive. It doesn't remember where you ROMs are without a lot of fiddling, and switching between games is very cumbersome, making a session of "trying out a bunch of games" an exercise in frustration, even when they are all for the same console and the same dir.

Even though a bunch of shaders and filters exist, they are so "schizophrenic" (sprinkled into many different menus in an inane way) that they are useless in practice. I spent *a lot* of time with those alone and I have to say that I couldn't make the screen resemble a real CRT TV. Again, I don't understand why they put this low-level fiddling onto the user instead of just having actual "presets", or at least providing that option.

Is RetroArch really the most user-friendly "general" emulator? Or is there something which I can just throw any ROM on for any console and it will instantly go fullscreen and visually resemble the console in question without me having to spend eight years of my life figuring out individual settings for everything like in RetroArch?